# How can I use Image Capture on OS X to import photos off my Lumia 925?

Tags: photos, macos

I like the Image Capture app on OS X just because its super simple and I can drag and drop and stuff to the desktop or delete photos off the device. Of course this works with iOS devices, but was curious if there was a way to use it on Lumias? Yes, I know about the Windows Phone OS X app, but for what I want to do it's just not nearly as good since I don't want to "sync" photos I just want to export them one time.